# Python convert csv to xlsx, however getting UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsx

I am trying to convert a csv file to a .xlsx file using PyExcel.

Here is some example data I have in the CSV file.

```
1.34805E+12,STANDARD,Jose,Sez,,La Pica, 16 o,Renedo de Piélagos,,39470,Spain,,No,No,1231800,2
```

I am having issues with the special characters, if there are none it line

```
merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob("uploadorders.csv"), "uploadorders.xlsx")
```

Has no problems, however if it does have special characters such as

```
Piélagos
```

or

```
Lücht
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 26: invalid continuation byte
```

I am unsure what to do about this, I have resorted to downloading the file, and re-saving it in excel.

Comment: uploadorders.csv is not utf8 formatted. In order to decode it, you will need to use latest version of pyexcel and pyexcel-io, and specify source encoding. `merge_all_to_a_book function` cannot accept encoding at the moment. you may want to try: `pyexcel.save_as(file_name="uploadorders.csv", encoding="your_encoding", dest_file_name="uploadorders.xlsx")`. Or try to use pyexcel-cli package, then you can do `pyexcel transcode --csv-source-encoding your_encoding uploadorders.csv uploadorders.xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

You get the UnicodeDecodeError because the encoding python uses to read the csv is different from the one used to save the file.

Try to save the file as UTF-8 or use the correct encoding to read it: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html